# Solar time correction due to longitudinal difference

Tags: astronomy

I've been always calculating the correction in solar time due to difference between observer's meridian and the meridian on which the local standard time is based using the following formula *"Design of Solar Thermal Systems" (Elsayed et al.)*:

$$\text{Solar Time} = \text{Civil Time} + \text{EOT} \pm 4(sl - ll)$$

Where $\text{EOT}$ is the equation of time, $sl$ is standard meridian for local time zone and $ll$ is is the longitude of the location in question. The $\pm$ term is taken as positive in the western hemisphere and negative in the eastern one.

However, while reading *"Solar Engineering of Thermal Processes" (Duffie and Beckman)* I found that they simply omitted the "$\pm$":

$$\text{Solar Time} = \text{Civil Time} + \text{EOT} + 4(sl - ll)$$

Does this mean that the previous equation is valid only for the western hemisphere or am I missing something?

Comment: Surely the difference comes out in the direction in which the local longitude is taken with respect to the standard meridian? If your system defines longitude as positive in the eastern hemisphere (becoming increasingly positive as you move eastward) and negative in the western hemisphere (becoming increasingly negative as you move westward), then you don't need the $\pm$.

Comment: (If on the other hand you use a system in which longitude is always defined as positive, i.e. "+30 deg W" or "+30 deg E", then you need to use the $\pm$ sign appropriately to take account of the different direction in which you're moving as you increase/decrease your longitude.)